# How to get last modified date from Microsoft sharepoint site's RSS Feed?

Tags: sharepoint, rss

From Microsoft Sharepoint site's RSS Feed, I am geting pubDate and lastBuildDate. I want last modified date of a file. Is this possible? If yes, can you please tell me how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right there in the View Settings

[image]

If this is not an answer to your question it is because your question is almost impossible to understand.

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood :( I wanted last modified date in RSS Feed Response. I can clearly see modified date in my Sharepoint front page. But when I execute RSS Feed of the sharepoint, I can see only pubDate and lastBuildDate field and not last modified date field. Am I making sense? :)

Comment: thanks for your help. I got the solution. You gave me a nice hint.